# What should the "author" field for a LinkedIn UGC post be for Showcase/Brand pages?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to specify an author for a UGC post to a showcase page. I am expecting that the author of the showcase post is the showcase page itself, which is what happens when I manually create a post, but this doesn't seem to work with the API.

Let's say I have a showcase `urn:li:organizationBrand:123456`. If I specify the showcase as the author (`"author": "urn:li:organizationBrand:123456`) I get an error about an invalid "author" field. But if I wrap the brand URN ID with "organization" instead of "organizationBrand" (`"author": "urn:li:organization:123456"`) *it works* but I have not found this interchangeability documented anywhere.

This same workaround works for retrieving post stats (`/organizationalEntityShareStatistics`).

Can anyone explain what the right approach is supposed to be?
Are organization brand URNs meant to effectively be an alias of organization URNs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the organizationalEntityAcls API to find your URN. organization URNs are not necessarily interchangeable with organizationBrand URNs.

For example:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee
```

```
  "paging": {
    "count": 10,
    "start": 0
  },
  "elements": [
    {
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:R8302pZx",
      "organizationalTarget": "urn:li:organization:1000"
    }
  ]
}
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control#find-access-control-information